# Prove permutation of jordan blocks

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A and B be square and

H=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    A&0  \\
    0 & B
  \end{bmatrix}

Prove that $J_H$=

\begin{bmatrix}
     J_A& 0  \\
    0 & J_B
  \end{bmatrix}

up to a permutation of J blocks. I am not sure how to start tis problem.

Comment: 1. It's in Jordan form, 2. Jordan form is unique up to permutation, 3. Its similar to H. Hence it is the Jordan form for H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=SJ_AS^{-1}$ and $B=TJ_BT^{-1}$ then 
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0\\0 & B
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
S & 0\\0 & T
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
J_A & 0\\0 & J_B
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
S & 0\\0 & T
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}.
$$